# Правильная реализация добавления уникального значения в бд через jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, jdbc

Есть такой код

```
public boolean addVisitor (Visitor visitor){
        boolean isAdded = false;
        try (PreparedStatement statement =  connection.prepareStatement
                    ("INSERT INTO visitors (address,rm_host,rm_port,method,user_agent) values (?,?,?,?,?)")){

            statement.setString(1,visitor.getRemoteAddress());
            statement.setString(2,visitor.getRemoteHost());
            statement.setString(3,visitor.getRemotePort());
            statement.setString(4,visitor.getRequestMethod());
            statement.setString(5,visitor.getUserAgent());
            statement.execute();

           if(statement.getWarnings()==null)
               isAdded =true;

        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isAdded;
    }
```

Он пытается добавить в бд запись, если запись в бд уже есть то в стейтменте появляться еxception что запись существует и значение не добавлено. В логе томкета `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '127.0.0.1' for key 'address_UNIQUE'` Насколько правильно я реализовал способ добавления уникальных записей в бд? Это все можно реализовать на java создав лист, добавляя и проверяя наличие в нем записей, потом уже заносить их в базу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше сначала селектом проверить есть ли такой визитор, если нет, то добавить, если есть то сообщить что уже существует.

Comment: Можно вместо селекта в секции `catch` добавить соответствующую обработку `SQLExceprion`.